# Not able to correlate the graph and table for the I2t rating in a fuse datasheet

Tags: power-supply, power, protection, circuit-protection, fuses

In  the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/643/ds_cp_c2q_series-1313118.pdf), the I<sup>2</sup>t rating of a 5A fuse is 0.055 at 10 times In.

[image]

Using the same value to estimate the trip time for the 10 A condition, I get 0.0022 seconds. In the graph below, it comes around 0.02 seconds.

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I<sup>2</sup>t rating actually represents the melting "energy" therefore it should have been I<sup>2</sup>Rt which comes from \$E = \int P \ dt\$. R here is the internal resistance of the fuse which assumed to be "constant" so it makes sense to specify I<sup>2</sup>t.

But R doesn't have to be constant, although depends on a few factors such as environmental cooling. A fuse is basically a conductor and has a resistance which increases with temperature. When a current passes through it, it dissipates some power and this dissipation causes the temperature, therefore the resistance, to increase.

For 10 times the nominal current i.e. 50 Amps, the melting rating is given as 0.055.

$$
E_{50}=(I^2 t)_{50} \ R_{50} = 0.055 \ R_{50}
$$

where \$R_{50}\$ is the fuse resistance for 50 Amps of current.

According to the average time-current curve given in the question, t is about 0.02 seconds for 10 Amps.

$$
E_{10}=(I^2 t)_{10} \ R_{10} = 2 \ R_{10}
$$

where \$R_{10}\$ is the fuse resistance for 10 Amps of current.

If we assume the melting energy ratings equal i.e. \$E_{50}=E_{10}\$ then we'll obtain

$$
R_{50}\approx 36 \ R_{10}
$$

which makes sense because the temperature rise (therefore the resistance change) can be higher at 50 Amps, compared to the one shown in Andy's answer which apparently has relatively lower (maybe negligible) resistance change.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like **bad data sheet information**. For instance, look at [a different data sheet](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-0678l-series.pdf) for Bel Fuse type 0678L: -

[image]

If you use the graph of the 10 amp fuse, ten times \$I_n\$ is 100 amps and this gives a melt-time of under 0.01 seconds (maybe 7 or 8 ms).

Then if you use the \$I^2\text{ sec}\$ figure of 50 from the table you get this: -

$$I^2t\hspace{1cm}=\hspace{1cm} 50 \hspace{1cm}\text{or}\hspace{1cm}t=\dfrac{50}{100^2}\hspace{1cm}=\hspace{1cm}\text{5 ms}$$

That's not a million miles from the graph (7 or 8 ms).